# onvif to retrieve log files from ip-camera

Tags: python-3.x, camera

As I am trying to get log files out of the camera in python console, would you guys say were the log files of camera gonna be and by following the onvif documentation, I tried using this code:

```
log=cam.devicemgmt.GetSystemLog({'Logtype': 'System'})
print(log)
```

**errors:**

> The SystemLogType type doesn't accept collections as value
>   GetSystemLog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'LogIype'.

I connected camera using onvif in python console, now I need to retrieve log files from the camera using onvif

Comment: I think it's just a typo. It should be `LogType` instead of `Logtype`

Comment: C:\Python36\python.exe C:/Helios/Helios-Client/ajay3.py
{
    'Binary': None,
    'String': '\nNo available system logs'
}

Process finished with exit code 0